# Using is_page() in functions.php not working at all

Tags: php, conditional-tags

Trying to run a custom script on a single page using is_page in functions.php not working at all. I have a function called load_gh_boards that would enquque a script, only on a certain page (79):

```
function load_gh_boards() {
if( is_page(79) ){
    wp_register_script( 'gh-jobs-board', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/gh-jobs-board.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'load_gh_boards');
```

This is inside a theme enqueue function that is loading all of my styles and scripts:

```
function theme_enqueue() {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    wp_register_style( 'main-style', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/css/style.css?' . time() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'main-vendor', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/vendor.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    ///etc...

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-vendor' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script' );

    ///load_gh_boards
}
```

No result. Any help or insight at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't replace the wrong code in your question with the correct code from the answer. If you do this, future visitors won't have a chance to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_page(79)` is asking if the current main query is a page, specifically page 79

**But the main query hasn't happened yet**

This function has to be called inside the main loop or at the very least inside the template, but the `init` hook is way too early for this.

Instead, make sure you use the body class, and load the script on all pages. Then, check if the body tag has the css class `page-id-79`.

### Other Notes

- You don't enqueue on the `init` hook, you're meant to enqueue on the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook
- It would be simpler to return early e.g. `if ( is_admin() ) return;`
- Don't enqueue jQuery, instead add it as a dependency so WP knows how to output the scripts in the correct order
- main-style and main-vendor are very generic names, you might encounter clashes, prefix them, e.g. `pji-main-vendor`
- `theme_enqueue` is also a very generic function name, you should prefix that too
- You can register and enqueue at the same time using `wp_enqueue_script`. If you pass everything to that function there's no need to call `wp_register_script`
- Indent your code, modern code editors will do this automatically for free, zero effort. Sublime or Atom are examples of free software that will do this for you, there really are no excuses

Comment: So basically you're saying to forget the conditional tag and use javascript to determine whether the page has the class. I had initially thought to do it this way but it seemed to me that a WP approach would be much cleaner...

Comment: just added code to footer.php.  `<?php 
 if ( is_page('join-us')) { 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://...wp-content/themes/.../js/gh-jobs-board.js"></script>';
 } 
?>`

Comment: There are other ways of doing it, but you should definately do it via the enqueue system

Comment: If the script can't be loaded in the functions.php (because of the necessity of a `is_page` function), then how do I enqueue it with the others?

Comment: The problem is not how you're doing it, but **when** you're doing it, the `init` hook is way too early

Answer (score 5):

This is absolutely working for me right now:

```
add_action('get_header', function() {
    if(is_page('566')) {

        function sp_enqueue_script() {
            wp_enqueue_script(
                'sp-custom-script',
                get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/sp_script.js',
                array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true
            );
        }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sp_enqueue_script' );
    }
});
```

[is_page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) doesn't work in functions.php because the main query hasn't loaded yet, so wait for the header to load.

Last boolean in the `wp_enqueue_script` hook is for the script to be enqueued in the footer, so it runs faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
function theme_enqueue() {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
wp_register_script( 'main-script', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/script.js', array(), '1.0', true );
wp_register_script( 'gh-jobs-board', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/gh-jobs-board.js', array(), '1.0', true );
///etc...
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-vendor' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script' );
///etc...

if( is_page(79) ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'gh-jobs-board' );
}
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a mistype in your code. It's `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `wp_enqueue_script`. That might be the issue.

Also, you shouldn't use `wp_enqueue_scripts` inside another `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Simply add your conditional in the `theme_enqueue()` function like this:

```
function theme_enqueue() {
if ( ! is_admin() ) {

    wp_register_style( 'main-style', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/css/style.css?' . time() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-style' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'main-vendor', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/vendor.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    ///etc...

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-vendor' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-script' );

    if( is_page(79) ){
        wp_register_script( 'gh-jobs-board', get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' ) . '/js/gh-jobs-board.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue');
```

I assume that the `theme_enqueue()` function is hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` itself.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the code. I don't believe the issue is with `wp_enqueue_script` -- this code was working before I started this change.

Comment: The `init` hook is too soon for enqueuing scripts. Use `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead.

Comment: switched `init` to `wp_enqueue_scripts` in functions.php. Works. Changed the code above. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You Register the Script, but you don't enqueue it.
Add wp_enqueue_script('gh-jobs-board'); to your conditional function.

Comment: Thanks I've updated the code --- still not working but closer.